# Trying to display image in guillotine.js with dynamic width & height. Working fine with fixed width & height

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-guillotine

Trying to display image in guillotine.js with dynamic width & height. Working fine with fixed width & height.

```
jQuery(function() {

      var picture = $('#sample_picture');

      // Make sure the image is completely loaded before calling the plugin
      picture.one('load', function(){
        // Initialize plugin (with custom event)
        picture.guillotine({

         var mysize = '<?php echo $size1 ; ?>';
         switch(mysize) {

         case '9x11':
          width: 268, 
          height: 375,
          break;
          }
          eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'});
```

Its working fine with fixed width & height

```
picture.guillotine({

          width: 314, 
          height: 224,
          }
          eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'});
```

Note : Variable $size1 from php assigned to mysize correctly.

Help me sort out this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### the main

Your method to work not is so good, you could know about of `identation` and later is understand how work the programing lenguage. Later that saw your develop problem i try to solve your code issue and i could solved it seeing you **fixed example(has errors)** and i did it. i hope help you

```
jQuery(function() {
let picture = $('#sample_picture');

// Make sure the image is completely loaded before calling the plugin
picture.one('load', ()=>{
    // Initialize plugin (with custom event)


    let mysize = '<?php echo $size1 ; ?>',
        sizes={}
    switch(mysize) {

        case '9x11':
            sizes={
                width: 268, 
                height: 375,
            }
        break;
    }
    picture.guillotine(sizes
    eventOnChange: 'guillotinechange'});
```